# Why the Address tag never gets read from a vcard?

Tags: c#, regex, vcf-vcard

Hello i have a little application that reads vcards. The strange part is that the address never gets read. I have a little sample vcard that i try to use. So here we go:

The string for the regex from the vcard:

```
"BEGIN:VCARDN:Huster;Hugo;;TestAdmin;HHUADR;INTL;PARCEL;WORK:;;Musterstra�e 10;Musterstadt;Niede�sterreich;3587;AustriaADR;DOM;PARCEL;HOME:;;Husterstra�e 10;Husterstadt;Wien;8897;AustriaEMAIL;INTERNET:hugo.huster@gmail.comEMAIL;INTERNET:hugo.huster@hotmail.comORG:Hugo GmbhTEL;WORK:12345678TEL;FAX;WORK:--342342TEL;CELL:45364321TEL;HOME:028560803TITLE:DeveloperURL;WORK:www.example.deURL:www.hug.atEND:VCARD"
```

and this is the regex i try to use for the address:

```
@"(\n(?<strElement>(ADR))) (;*(?<strAttr>(HOME|WORK)))*  (:(?<strPo>([^;]*)))  (;(?<strBlock>([^;]*)))  (;(?<strStreet>([^;]*)))  (;(?<strCity>([^;]*))) (;(?<strRegion>([^;]*))) (;(?<strPostcode>([^;]*)))(;(?<strNation>[^\n\r]*))";
```

and the code where I use it:

```
case "ADR":
    regex = @"(\n(?<strElement>(ADR))) (;*(?<strAttr>(HOME|WORK)))*  (:(?<strPo>([^;]*)))  (;(?<strBlock>([^;]*)))  (;(?<strStreet>([^;]*)))  (;(?<strCity>([^;]*))) (;(?<strRegion>([^;]*))) (;(?<strPostcode>([^;]*)))(;(?<strNation>[^\n\r]*))";
    mc = regex.Matches(vCardLine);
    if (mc.Count > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < mc.Count; i++)
        {
            VCardComponents.Address address = new VCardComponents.Address();
            v.Addresses.Add(address);
            m = mc[i];
            ss = m.Groups["strAttr"].Value;
            if (ss == "HOME")
                address.HomeWorkType = VCardComponents.HomeWorkTypes.HOME;
            else if (ss == "WORK")
                address.HomeWorkType = VCardComponents.HomeWorkTypes.WORK;

            address.POBox = m.Groups["strPo"].Value;
            address.Ext = m.Groups["strBlock"].Value;
            address.Street = m.Groups["strStreet"].Value;
            address.Locality = m.Groups["strCity"].Value;
            address.Region = m.Groups["strRegion"].Value;
            address.Postcode = m.Groups["strPostcode"].Value;
            address.Country = m.Groups["strNation"].Value;
        }
    }
    break;
```

and here for example a working Regex for Org:

```
@"(?<strElement>(ORG)) ((;(ENCODING=)?(?<strAttr>(QUOTED-PRINTABLE)))|(;CHARSET=UTF-?8))*  (:(?<strORG>(([^;^\n\r]*(=\n\r)?)*[^;^\n\r]*[^;]*(\n\r)?) ))(;(?<strDept>(([^;^\n\r]*(=\n\r)?)*[^;^\n\r]*[^;]*(\n\r)?) ))?";
```

The Regex follow always the same pattern but somehow it wont work for Adresses its always null. And i have no clue why. I tried it with google and with a tutorial on codeproject but had no luck so far. I know that there are libarys around but i am supposed to use regex stuff.

So any help or advise would be great and thx for your time.

Comment: Couldn't you reduce the code to the minimum to help us help you quicker?  I tried your regex against the string you provided and it did not match the string at all.

Comment: Well i tried to reduce it to the minimum. The code is just one part switch statement with many cases. Mabey i should post the string when the vcard gets read? i just read it with textBox1.Text =  File.ReadAllText(openFileDialog1.FileName); Mabey i should post this code?

Comment: Just the string, the regex you run against it, what is not matched but should. You simple vCard - I guess - is the input. The regex below it does not match the string.

Comment: hope its now clearer. There are switch statements with cases. So when the case ADR shows up it should use ADR Regex.

Comment: No, sorry, still unclear. At least I cannot get it.

Comment: Do you have a reason for preferring to write this code yourself rather than e.g. using a library or code that someone else has already written and debugged? E.g. a quick search uncovered [`EWSoftware/PDI`](https://github.com/EWSoftware/PDI) which seems to have a VCard parser already.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever well the reason is my supervisor he says it better to use your own stuff so you know what you are dealing with sadly....

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever hi just wanted to say thx for the tipp with the libary. I was able to convince my superiors that its much better and faster to use a libary or nugget. Works great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex just doesn't match the `ADR` property.

Your ADR field contains the parameters

```
INTL;PARCEL;WORK
DOM;PARCEL;HOME
```

But your regex only allows `HOME` and `WORK`.

Note that your VCARD uses the deprecated VCard 2.1 syntax. I recommend to switch to VCard 3.0 or vCard 4.0.

Also, note that there are few more issues with your way to parse the properties. It will fail when parsing the newer vCard 3.0 or vCard 4.0 syntax. It will also fail if the values contain escaped sequences like `\;` and it will fail if the lines are folded (see [RFC 6350](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6350#section-3.2)).

Comment: thanks now it works. And about the vCard Version thanks again i work on it. Didnt noticed it was my first try with REGEX and vCards.